# copy std::vector<uint8_t> to char *

Tags: vector, char, copy

I have two variables defined as

```
std::vector<uint8_t> var; 
char* test;
```

I have tried using reinterpret_cast. But its not working . Is there any way like `"strcpy"` to copy or type conversion 
I want to copy `'var'` to `'test'`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have allocated enough chars in memory to hold the contents of what is stored in your vector. You could use `std::copy`like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
int main(int agrc, char** argv){
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> var;
    //fill "var" here somehow

    char* test = new char[var.size()];//init this with the correct size

    std::copy(var.begin(),var.end(),test);
    delete [] test;
    return 0;
}
```

Please keep in mind that this will fail if you have not allocated at least `var.size()` elements for `test`. Additionally if `test` is intended to be a c-string you will need to allocate `var.size()+1` elements and insert `\0` into the last element of `test` assuming that `var` is not already null terminated.